# Get parameter value from extended abstract class using 'Reflect'

Tags: java, class, reflection, casting

I would like to get `param2` value from a extended class that has common properties shared with an abstract class 'B' like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Fields {

    public class A{

        public abstract class B{
            int param1;
            String param2;
            public abstract void B ();
        }

        public class B0 extends B{
            @Override
            public void B() {
                this.param1 = 0;
                this.param2 = "Mario";
            }                                    
        }

        public class B1 extends B{
            @Override
            public void B() {
                this.param1 = 1;
                this.param2 = "Anna";
            }            
        }        

        B1 b1 = new B1();        

        public A (){
            b1.B();
        }

        public B0 GetB(Object AnyB){
            B0 tmp_b0 = (B0) AnyB;
            return tmp_b0;
        }
    }

    public Fields(){
        A a = new A();
        Field[] f = a.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (int i = 0; i<f.length; i++){
            f[i].setAccessible(true);
            Object obj = f[i];
            String p2;
            p2 = a.GetB(obj).param2;
            System.out.println(p2);
        }        
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Fields f = new Fields();        
    }
}
```

Formally the instruction `B0 tmp_b0 = (B0) AnyB;` is correct, but in runtime I get the error : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.reflect.Field cannot be cast to Fields$A$B0`.

Why ?

There is a way to get the value of parameter `param1` or `param2`.

There is a way ?

Thanks

Comment: With the new version of the question, I'd *still* strongly suggest that you start following Java naming conventions, and avoid nested classes unless you genuinely need them.

Answer (score 3):

(Note: this answer was written before the question was completely changed. I'm leaving it like this for now in the hope that the question will be rolled back.)

> Formally the instruction `B0 tmp_b0 = (B0) AnyB;` is correct,

Well it's valid Java code, but I wouldn't expect it to work in this case. You're currently passing the `Field` reference - that's *not* a `B0`, so you're getting an exception.

You don't want to pass the `Field` itself - I suspect you want to pass the *value* of the field with respect to `a`:

```
Object fieldValue = f[i].get(a);
String p2 = a.GetB(fieldValue);
```

Even then, you'll *still* get a `ClassCastException` for the `b1` field, because that has an execution-time type of `B1`, but you're trying to cast to `B0`. An instance of `B1` is *not* an instance of `B0`.

It's not terribly clear what you're trying to achieve here - why you have a `B0` class at all, when you never create an instance of it - but I would suggest trying to get things working *without* reflection first, and then when you *do* use reflection, differentiate between the concept of a field (as represented by `Field`) and the value of a field.

(I'd also suggest not using nested classes as much, and following Java naming conventions, but those are somewhat separate.)

Comment: I just changed the content of question above.
Thank you

Comment: @user2552555: That's somewhat unhelpful, as it now makes my answer look completely invalid. I suggest you roll back your question to the previous revision, and ask a new one that looks like this - as it would have a completely different answer.

Comment: Ok I performed the roll back as you suggested. Sorry for the error!